# My li is floating left at larger screen but when it is on extra small screen the li does down. How can I put my li float left at smaller screen too?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a navbar. In this navbar I used two `li` tages. One is of language and another is of currency. When I make the screen size to extra small I want the `li`tags to float left. But it goes down of another. How can I fixed this problem.

Also my collapse button is not positioning in correct place. Need a solution for that too.

I have tried with `float-xs-left`class and also css media query. None of them worked.

I want the "EN" and "USD" option to float left an extra small screen and I also want the search and total amount of money option to look cool

Comment: Please add relevant code to help you better !

Comment: Please include a [mcve] that includes the HTML and CSS of the elements that are trying to fix

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you asked for is to use the CSS property `display: flex` on the parent element of the `li` tags (for instance, a `ul` tag) in conjunction with the `flex-wrap: nowrap`. Here is an example that might work on small screens:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: .5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: slategrey;
}

li {
  margin: .5em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Language: French</li>
    <li>Currency: Euros €</li>
  </ul>
<nav>
```